# Android intercept internal library method call

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have sdk of logging android.
Client (app) can use other logging sdk like mine.
I want to handle the call of external method log.
For example, I want to log "Hello word" for each call of Log.i.
I have some idea for intercept (MethodInvocationHandler).

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming *questions*. What is your *question*?

Comment: There are lot library to report user event from app to reporting tool.
I want for example to intercept these events or dynamically insert a code au runtime. Do you have idea?
thanks